# wxPython grid tooltips not working

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I am trying to use Mike Driscoll's solution for making tooltip messages in a wxPython grid as explained here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/04/wxpython-grid-tips-and-tricks/.  Here is my minimal example.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class GridFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1)
        self.grid.ClearGrid()
        self.grid.CreateGrid(10, 5)
        self.grid.AutoSize()
        self.grid.GetGridWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, lambda event: self.onMouseOver(event, self.grid))
        hbox.Add(self.grid, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        hbox.Fit(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def onMouseOver(self, event, grid):
        """                                                                                                                                        
        Displays a tooltip over any cell in a certain column                                                                                       
        """
        x, y = grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(),event.GetY())
        coords = grid.XYToCell(x, y)
        col = coords[1]
        row = coords[0]

        if col == 1:
            msg = "This is Row %s, Column %s!" % (row, col)
            print msg
            event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString(msg)
        else:
            event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString('')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(redirect=False)
    app.frame = GridFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.frame.Center()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The tooltip simply doesn't show up.  The print statement works as expected, so I know the binding worked and the event is being caught.  I assume I'm missing something simple - maybe I need to initialize the tooltip somewhere? - but I'm not sure what.  Any ideas?

Update:

The problem seems to be a combination of the version of wxPython and the platform.  The code works as expected on Windows with wxPython 2.8.10.1.  It fails on Mac with 2.9.2.4, but succeeds with 3.0.2.0.  In general we need the users of our GUI to install Enthought's Canopy distribution of Python, which comes with 2.9.2.4 (the failing version of wxPython).

Using event.Skip() doesn't seem to matter.

I'll approach this differently now that I know it is a wxPython version issue.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
def onMouseOver(self, event, grid):
    """
    Displays a tooltip over any cell in a certain column
    """
    x, y = grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(),event.GetY())
    coords = grid.XYToCell(x, y)
    col = coords[1]
    row = coords[0]

    if col == 1:
        msg = "This is Row %s, Column %s!" % (row, col)
        print msg
        self.grid.GetGridWindow().SetToolTipString(msg)
    else:
        self.grid.GetGridWindow().SetToolTipString('')
    #wx.Window.ToolTip()
    #wx.Window.Tool
    event.Skip()
```

im not sure why you are passing grid since it is available via the self attribute

Comment: This code doesn't show a tooltip either (on my Mac).  Does it show up for you?  As to your comment, in my actual application there are several different grids, which is why I'm passing it to onMouseOver.

Comment: it works fine on windows using self.grid or the locally passed in grid ... I copied and pasted your code directly and just changed those two lines and it works ... not sure why it wouldnt on a mac

Comment: One more reason for me to get a Mac...so I can update some of my old articles.